# How to return a numpy array with values where, the common indices values for 2 arrays are both greater than 0

Tags: python, numpy

I want the first array to display it's values only when common indices values of both the arrays are greater than zero else make it zero. I'm not really sure how to frame the question. Hopefully the expected output provides better insight.

I tried playing around with np.where, but I can't seem to make it work when 2 arrays are provided.

```py
a = np.array([0,2,1,0,4])
b = np.array([1,1,3,4,0])
# Expected Output
a = ([0,2,1,0,0])
```

Comment: `a * (a * b).astype(bool)`

Comment: `a * ((a>0) * (b > 0))` to avoid overflow

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota This is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

The zip function, which takes elements of two arrays side by side, is useful here. You don't necessarily need an np/numpy function.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,2,1,0,4])
b = np.array([1,1,3,4,0])

c = np.array([x if x * y > 0 else 0 for x,y in zip(a, b)])
print(c)
```

Comment: If the arrays are already `numpy` arrays, it seems silly to use something much slower than `numpy` methods that produces a list at the end.  Also your ternary operator is in the wrong place, this is invalid syntax

Comment: Good point. I edited too quickly and it should be fixed now. Your one-line solution is definitely slicker and more generalizable. I guess I've been seeing zip lately and finally got comfortable, so I've been using it a lot.